# style listview items in javafx/css

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to style the labels in my listview similar to the labels in the picture. When I use nth-child on any item in my css nothing happens. Without the nth-child all items in my listview are italic.

```
.list-cell:nth-child(0) {
    -fx-font-style: italic;
} 

.list-cell:nth-child(1) {
    -fx-font-style: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `nth-child` pseudoselector does not work in javafx. You need to do this from code using a custom `ListCell` implementation. (Override `updateIndex` according to your needs.)

Comment: thank you. Now I can finally style the labels.